# How can I edit a variable and also run multiple commands in a FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables

I want to run a FOR LOOP to create files using the variables that it returns, and then modify the resulting variables and output.

I am trying to create files based upon the parent folder name, which contain the children in the output file, and then append a string to the beginning of each line in the output file.

```
REM THIS SECTION IS JUST TO RECREATE MY ISSUE.  THESE FILES AND FOLDERS ALREADY EXIST.  
REM THEY ARE NOT SEQUENTIAL AND HAVE RANDOM NAMES.
REM ==================================================================

md %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1
md %temp%\looptest\folder2
md %temp%\looptest\folder3

echo echo folder2-file1-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file1.bat
echo echo folder2-file1-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file1.bat
echo echo folder2-file1-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file1.bat
echo echo folder2-file2-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file2.bat
echo echo folder2-file2-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file2.bat
echo echo folder2-file2-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file2.bat
echo echo folder2-file3-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file3.bat
echo echo folder2-file3-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file3.bat
echo echo folder2-file3-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder2\folder2-file3.bat

echo echo folder3-file1-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file1.bat
echo echo folder3-file1-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file1.bat
echo echo folder3-file1-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file1.bat
echo echo folder3-file2-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file2.bat
echo echo folder3-file2-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file2.bat
echo echo folder3-file2-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file2.bat
echo echo folder3-file3-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file3.bat
echo echo folder3-file3-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file3.bat
echo echo folder3-file3-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder3\folder3-file3.bat

echo echo subfolder1-file1-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file1-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file1-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file1-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file1-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file1-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file2-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file2-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file2-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file2-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file2-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file2-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file3-line1 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file3-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file3-line2 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file3-extratext.bat
echo echo subfolder1-file3-line3 >> %temp%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file3-extratext.bat


REM THIS IS WHERE MY ACTUAL QUESTION STARTS
REM ========================================================

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a:d /b /s %temp%\looptest\') DO (

    set "var=%%G"
    set "var=!var:%temp%\looptest\=!

    (
        dir /b %temp%\looptest\!var!

    )>>"%temp%\looptest\!var!-output.bat"


)
```

`folder1-output.bat` is unusable because there are no files in it's child folder, only another folder, and that's ok, I can ignore it if needed.

Right now, the file `folder2-output.bat` contains the lines:

```
folder2-file1.bat
folder2-file2.bat
folder2-file3.bat
```

I want `folder2-output.bat` to contain the lines:

```
call folder2-file1.bat
call folder2-file2.bat
call folder2-file3.bat
```

I want `folder3-output.bat` to contain the lines:

```
call folder3-file1.bat
call folder3-file2.bat
call folder3-file3.bat
```

I want `folder1\subfolder1-output.bat` to contain the lines:

```
call subfolder1-file1-extratext.bat
call subfolder1-file2-extratext.bat
call subfolder1-file3-extratext.bat
```

But I can't figure out where to echo out the CALL command to add to the FOR LOOP.

I think I need to do something like

```
    set "var2=%%G"
    set "var2=CALL !var2!
```

and then

```
ECHO !var2! !var! >>"%temp%\looptest\!var!-output.bat"
```

But I'm not sure where to put that in the FOR loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=%temp%\looptest"
FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%G IN (*) DO (
 ECHO examining directory "%%G"
 rem if the directory contains any .bat files then create a file
 rem called leafname-output.bat in the parent containing
 rem "call each-batfilename-found"
 IF EXIST "%%G\*.bat" (
  ECHO "%%G" contains batchfiles
  ECHO "%%~dpG" is parent
  ECHO "%%~nxG" is leafname
  FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /b /a-d "%%G\*.bat"') DO >>"%%G-output.bat" ECHO CALL "%%~nxa"
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO "%%G" does NOT contain batchfiles
 )
 ECHO -------------------------------------
)

dir/s "%sourcedir%\*-output.bat"

GOTO :EOF
```

Interesting little adventure. Excellent that you provided code to create your testfiles - but it appears that you've sensibly changed your `temp` directory to a location not containing spaces, so I'm not sure it'd work with a vanilla installation.

You have evidently studied `delayedexpansion` but it appears you've become more concerned with the *method* of solving the problem than targeting the *solution*.

I believe the `echo`es and commentary above adequately document the method I chose after analysing your *method* to determine *the problem to be solved*. You will no doubt now put a magnifying glass on the various uses of `for` as documented in `for /?` and with many examples here on SO. Of course, I may have missed the mark.

Naturally, if you do not delete the `*-output.bat` files before you start, you may encounter problems since the files are appended to and the `dir` looking for `*.bat` files will include the `...-output.bat` in the list delivered. Should be easily solved using a mutation of the final `dir/s` command listed.

Comment: The `For /D /R` looks quite similar ;-) +1

Answer (score 1):

For local testing on my Ramdisk A: I changed and simplified your batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\13\SO_57482013.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Base=A:\Test"
:: create folders
for %%D in (folder1\subfolder1 folder2 folder3) Do md "%Base%\looptest\%%D"
:: create files
for %%D in (folder2 folder3
) Do for /l %%F in (1,1,3
) Do for /l %%L in (1,1,3
) Do echo echo %%D-file%%F-line%%L >>"%Base%\looptest\%%D\%%D-file%%F.bat"
for /l %%F in (1,1,3
) Do for /l %%L in (1,1,3
) Do echo echo subfolder1-file%%F-line%%L >> "%Base%\looptest\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1-file%%F-extratext.bat"
```

This creates the following folder/file structure (with all files containing line1..3):

```
> tree a:\ /F
A:\
└───Test
    └───looptest
        ├───folder1
        │   └───subfolder1
        │           subfolder1-file1-extratext.bat
        │           subfolder1-file2-extratext.bat
        │           subfolder1-file3-extratext.bat
        │
        ├───folder2
        │       folder2-file1.bat
        │       folder2-file2.bat
        │       folder2-file3.bat
        │
        └───folder3
                folder3-file1.bat
                folder3-file2.bat
                folder3-file3.bat
```

IMO you are missing to include the folder name when calling the batch in the folder,
this changed routine will do:

```
REM THIS IS WHERE MY ACTUAL QUESTION STARTS
REM ========================================================

FOR /D /R "%Base%\looptest" %%G IN (*) Do (
  For %%F in (%%G\*.bat) Do Echo @Call %%~nxG\%%~nxF
) >"%%~dpG%%~nxG-output.bat"
```

So for example `A:\Test\looptest\folder2-output.bat` contains:

```
@Call folder2\folder2-file1.bat
@Call folder2\folder2-file2.bat
@Call folder2\folder2-file3.bat
```

And when executed from within folder `A:\Test\looptest` yields:

```
folder2-file1-line1
folder2-file1-line2
folder2-file1-line3
folder2-file2-line1
folder2-file2-line2
folder2-file2-line3
folder2-file3-line1
folder2-file3-line2
folder2-file3-line3
```